# How to install Sublime Text 2 packages via PackageControl from shell

Tags: sublimetext2, package-control

I'm writing a post-install script for my Ubuntu 12.04. The thing I need is to install PackageControl and all the other importent packages to Sublime Text 2 via just installed PackageControl from the shell. How can I do it? Give me some examples, please.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to write your own Code based on PackageControl to support Shell-Access, but that would overly complicate the Plugin-Installation-Process, since
Package-Installation in Sublime Text 2 is nothing more than putting files in its Packages-Directory.

I assume that you want to do this because you want to install Sublime Text on multiple PCs without the hassle of doing manual downloads from every PC.

Just create a fresh Sublime Text 2 Installation, install the Packages you need, and copy the Configuration-directory to each PC. The Configuration is in

```
~/.config/sublime-text-2
```

Copying this folder to every PC will copy the Plugins, too.

Comment: I just did it. But the goal is to install all the packages automatically and then copy my configuration. I don't want to install all the packages manually when using a new PC.
Maybe I can copy installed packages too?

Comment: Read "Copying this folder to every PC will copy the Plugins, too",
so yes, you can copy installed packages, too.

Comment: @gyzerok I believe package control will grab all of the packages listed in the `Package Control.sublime-settings` file at start up if they aren't already installed. You may want to test that to make sure, but I believe that is what occurs. If that's the case, you should really only need to grab the user folder and "install" package control from the shell. Then start up ST.